# org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15 - Tomcat 7, JDK incompatibilty?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, classformatexception

I tried upgrading to Java 8. When starting our tomcat7 server, with a Java 7-compiled .war file, I get the mysteriously error below.

Should I expect this to work? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294355/is-tomcat-7-now-compatible-with-java-7) says tomcat 7 should work with 1.6 and up.
I can't tell if Tomcat is to blame, or the .war. Switching out different Java versions I get:

- JDK 7.45 installed - works (same version used to compile .war)
- JDK 7.55 installed - fails as below
- JDK 8.05 installed - fails as below

Is tomcat to blame, or the .war?

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2032)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1923)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1891)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1877)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was seeing this error with Tomcat 7.0.26.

To answer your question, Tomcat is to blame: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53735

Upgrading to version 7.0.53 fixed it for me (according to the linked issue, the fix should be in 7.0.30 and later).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. I followed the error and I foud out I needed to upgrade to the latest version our maven dependency for ICU4J jar.

And the error is gone now:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
     <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
     <version>56.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Java 8 on my computer, but I wanted to **run** my **Tomcat using Java 7**.

The following solution worked for me.

In **`%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\`** (E.g.: C:\Tomcat\bin) add **setenv.bat** having the following content:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
set JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre
exit /B 0
```

When you run **startup.bat**, the following calls happen:

```
startup.bat
     |
     └── catalina.bat
               |
               └── setenv.bat
```

- see:

  ```
  if not exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" goto checkSetenvHome
  call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
  ```